# Best way to license Microsoft software as an independent developer

Tags: windows, visual-studio, licensing

I've recently switched from being an employee of a small consulting company to being an independent consultant and as time goes on I will need to upgrade Windows and Visual Studio. So what is the most affordable way to go about this for a small time developer?

My previous boss suggested I get a TechNet Plus subscription for OS licenses, I've done that and appears to be what I need, but open to other options for the future.

Visual Studio I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly what is the difference between Professional and Standard. Also I'd really like a digital version, but seems that expensive MSDN subscription is the only way?

Visual Studio 2008 Professional with MSDN Professional listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/aa718657.aspx) appears to be semi-reasonably priced at $1,199. That would make the TechNet Plus subscription unneeded.

Comment: Are you eligible http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend that if VS Express is not good enough, use Professional. Standard is missing some really useful features, like a Remote Debugger. Here is a detailed comparison:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2008/products/cc149003.aspx

I'd say cancel TechNet and get one of the bottom two MSDN Subscriptions, Visual Studio Professional with either MSDN Professional or with MSDN Premium.

Comment: MSDN Premium now includes Expression Blend2 & Web 2

Answer (score 5):

You have the Microsoft Empower for ISV program, see https://partner.microsoft.com/40011351

Gives you a full msdn pro subscription for two years.

Answer (score 2):

For non developer tools try Microsoft Action Pack
https://partner.microsoft.com/40016455
Then use Visual Studio Professional (in some exibitions you will get  this for free)
For the versioning use svn and not TeamSystem

Answer (score 2):

I realise that this doesn't apply to the asker but it it is relevent to the question.

Any **student developers** out there try [Microsfts Dream Spark scheme](https://downloads.channel8.msdn.com/). Visual Studio, Expression Studio, XNA and Server 2003 for free!

Office is also available to students for less than 60 bucks in [Microsfts `Ultimate Steal'](http://www.microsoft.com/student/discounts/theultimatesteal-us/default.aspx)

Comment: Do you have any idea how many packages of ramen noodles $60 could buy you? Do you? DO YOU?!

Answer (score 0):

I think that Visual Studio Professional with MSDN Subscription doesn't offer much value compared to just purchasing Visual Studio 2010 Pro. You get testing licenses for Windows Server and MSSQL, but that's it. And you can get by just fine without those 90% of the time.

But Visual Studio Premium with MSDN is a different story. You get access to most other server products (testing license only of course), and an Office Professional license. That's a much better value for a one-man shop in my opinion, if you can afford it.

Comment: It really depends upon your focus, though. As a Web developer, the Server and MSSQL licenses are exactly what I need to be really productive, and I have the bonus of getting desktop OSs as well. Your second point is completely valid.